# Php, factory and container objects needs each other, how to eliminate circular references

Tags: php

```
class Factory
{
    /**
     * @var Container
     */
    private $container;

    public function __construct(Container $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function createDate()
    {
        return new CustomDateClass(date(), $this->container->getDb());
    }
}

class Container
{
    /**
     * @var MySQL
     */
    private $db;

    /**
     * @return MySQL
     */
    public function getDb()
    {
        if ($this->db == null)
        {
             $this->db = new MySQL();
        }
        return $this->db;
    }

    /**
     * @return ObjectThatNeedFactory
     */
    public function getObjectThatNeedFactory()
    {
        if ($this->objectThatNeedFactory == null)
        {
             $this->objectThatNeedFactory = new ObjectThatNeedFactory($this->factory); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
        return $this->objectThatNeedFactory;
    }
}

$container = new Container();
$factory = new Factory($container);
```

here `Factory` creates object according to circumstances. It needs `Container` because some factoried objects nees object from this container. So far so good, until the `ObjectThatNeedFactory` class enters. `ObjectThatNeedFactory` needs this factory because it also may need to factory other object. At this point it looks like a circular-reference problem. How to untie / ravel this?

EDIT: I imagined that I could inject them later:

```
$container = new Container();
$factory = new Factory();
$container->injectFactory($factory);
$factory->injectContainer($container);
```

but it still smells bad

Comment: You should look into Dependency Injection instead of passing the factory around. I don't really see what you need both a factory and a container for? They seem to be doing more or less the same thing?

Comment: DI allows to have an instance once, isnt it? Now factory allows to create multiple times

Comment: With a proper container, you can define if you want the container to return the same instance or new instances, just like a factory. Look into some existing containers like Pimple,or Illuminates Container (the one Laravel is using and uses reflection for automatic dependency resolution/injection and is my personal container of choice.). No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: still I feel that Factory is a thing to create objects, and Container is another, to hold those object. Any object that has $factory is allowed to create instances it has. But $container cannot be passed to everyone, only some object may get objects that it has

Comment: The container creates objects if needed and stores them for reuse if they are defined as singletons. More or less all containers out there works like that. No need for the factory. Google for some DI containers, read about how they work and it will become clear. Passing a "generic" factory around to a bunch of different classes feels like an anti-pattern. (You will end up with hard dependencies all over the place).